# Moving buttons/entries using grid in tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I have just started learning tkinter and am having troubles with moving items around using grid. I am assuming this is an easy fix but I am trying to get my password entry and "generate password" button to be located much closer than they are as seen in the attached image (essentially I want everything aligned). How can I do this? I have looked on here and elsewhere but can't seem to find anything that replicates my problem.

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Password Manager")
window.config(padx=50, pady=50)

canvas = Canvas(height=200, width=200)
canvas.grid(column=1, row=0)
lock = PhotoImage(file="logo.png")
canvas.create_image(100, 100, image=lock)

website = Label(text="Website:")
website.grid(column=0, row=1)

email_user_name = Label(text="Email/Username:")
email_user_name.grid(column=0, row=2)

password = Label(text="Password:")
password.grid(column=0, row=3)

website_entry = Entry(width=35)
website_entry.grid(column=1, row=1, columnspan=2)

email_entry = Entry(width=35)
email_entry.grid(column=1, row=2, columnspan=2)

password_entry = Entry(width=21)
password_entry.grid(column=1, row=3)

generate_button = Button(text="Generate Password")
generate_button.grid(column=2, row=3)

add_button = Button(text="Add", width=30)
add_button.grid(column=1, row=4, columnspan=2)
window.mainloop()
```

[image: Buttons not aligning]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `sticky="e"` to `grid(...)` on the labels and `sticky="w"` on the entries:

```py
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Password Manager")
window.config(padx=50, pady=50)

canvas = Canvas(height=200, width=200)
canvas.grid(column=1, row=0)
lock = PhotoImage(file="logo.png")
canvas.create_image(100, 100, image=lock)

website = Label(text="Website:")
website.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky="e")

email_user_name = Label(text="Email/Username:")
email_user_name.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky="e")

password = Label(text="Password:")
password.grid(column=0, row=3, sticky="e")

website_entry = Entry(width=35)
website_entry.grid(column=1, row=1, columnspan=2, sticky="w")

email_entry = Entry(width=35)
email_entry.grid(column=1, row=2, columnspan=2, sticky="w")

password_entry = Entry(width=21)
password_entry.grid(column=1, row=3, columnspan=2, sticky="w")

generate_button = Button(text="Generate Password")
generate_button.grid(column=3, row=3, sticky="w")

add_button = Button(text="Add", width=30)
add_button.grid(column=1, row=4, columnspan=2)
window.mainloop()
```

Note that I have added `columnspan=2` to `password_entry.grid(...)` and moved `generate_button` to column 3.

Comment: Awesome, "sticky" was precisely what I was looking for that I didn't know existed... thanks so much!